# EditText keeps returning null?

Tags: android, null

```
public class Input extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    EditText mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1i); 
    String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
    EditText mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2i); 
    String val2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();

    double dVal1 = Double.parseDouble(val1); 
    double dVal2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);


  } 
}
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number1i"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your first value"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />   

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number2i"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your second value"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_marker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Add value"
        android:onClick="userInput1"
        android:textSize="22sp" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

The error:

```
12-05 08:57:17.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 08:57:17.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8420):     at com.example.whatever.input.onCreate(input.java:23)
```

Line 23 is

```
String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
```

Any help please?

I would presume because the value could be empty?

Comment: I think you should first check if the value is not empty and then try to use the toString

Comment: get edittext text value in onclick on Button.

Comment: If everything is correct..clean & build the project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code `mEditText1.getText()` will always be empty in `onCreate` unless you have to set `text` in it from XML

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I have when creating an onClick is that I want to pass these two values to my Google Maps API. So for instance, when I pass the two values to the onClick, the two values will assign a marker to Google Maps (the user will enter the latitude and longitude in the EditText). I am unable to assign the values on the Google Maps API from the onClick(). I can add a set marker in the onCreate, but I need the latitude and longitude set by the user.

Comment: You will need to set the Google Maps API marker from a `Button` click after checking that none of the `EditText` vales are null.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
if(val1 != null && val1 !=""){
 double dVal1 = Double.parseDouble(val1); //+handle parse error
}
```

//but you should get text in onClick method

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is because the `String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();` and `String val2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();` are on onCreate() they are executed before the user puts anything to the edittext try using them in an on click listener

Answer (score 1):

you can do null check for `edittext.getText()` & try it to put somewhere in code where you have an input for editext

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml EdiText Component to :

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/number1i"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your first value"
    android:text="Test Value"                      << Add this line
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Now try to run your code.

Hope this helps.