# Why would EditText display user input yet not hold that user input?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have encountered a very odd behavior that has me pulling my hair out. The EditText objects hold empty strings regardless of what is entered in them and I can't figure out why. I tried searching for similar entries, but

[EditText keeps returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395753/edittext-keeps-returning-null)
I get no error message, just failure of the EditText objects.

[EditText editable but getText() return empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716215/edittext-editable-but-gettext-return-empty-string)
I tried declaring the EditText objects as shown in that page, but it made no difference. Besides, my other Fragments used in the same situation have no such problems.

My search results provided nothing similar to what I'm experiencing.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvTitleDateField"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/date"
android:textSize="24sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentDate"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appointmentDate"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/appointmentDate"
android:layout_width="325dp"
android:layout_height="47dp"
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:ems="10"
android:autofillHints="@string/hint_tap_to_set_date"
android:hint="@string/hint_tap_to_set_date"
android:inputType="text"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitleDateField"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvTitleTimeField"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:text="@string/time"
android:textSize="24sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentTime"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appointmentTime"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/appointmentTime"
android:layout_width="311dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:autofillHints="@string/hint_tap_to_set_time"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/hint_tap_to_set_time"
android:inputType="text"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitleTimeField"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentDate"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvTitleNotificationField"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:text="@string/notification"
android:textSize="24sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentNotification"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appointmentNotification"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/appointmentNotification"
android:layout_width="256dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:autofillHints="@string/hint_tap_to_enter_notification"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/hint_tap_to_enter_notification"
android:inputType="number"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitleNotificationField"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentTime"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvNotes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:text="@string/notes"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentNotes"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appointmentNotes"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/appointmentNotes"
android:layout_width="301dp"
android:layout_height="44dp"
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:autofillHints="@string/notes"
android:ems="10"
android:gravity="start|top"
android:hint="@string/notes"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvNotes"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentEvent"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvEvent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:text="@string/event"
android:textSize="24sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentEvent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appointmentEvent"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/appointmentEvent"
android:layout_width="311dp"
android:layout_height="41dp"
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:autofillHints="@string/enter_event"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/enter_event"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvEvent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appointmentNotification"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the relevant parts of the fragment's code:

```
public class ScheduleAppointmentFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentNameProvider{
private static EditText date;
private static EditText time;
private static EditText notification;
private static EditText event;
private static EditText notes;
.
.
.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.d(TAG, "Entered: onCreate");
if (getArguments() != null) {
mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
}
sMedicalInformationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MedicalInformationViewModel.class);
if(getArguments() != null){
petId = getArguments().getInt(PET_ID_KEY);
name = getArguments().getString(PET_NAME_KEY);
appointmentId = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_ID_KEY);
appointmentDate = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_DATE_KEY);
appointmentTime = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_TIME_KEY);
appointmentNotification = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_NOTIFICATION_KEY);
appointmentEvent = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_EVENT_KEY);
appointmentNotes = getArguments().getString(APPOINTMENT_NOTES_KEY);
Log.d(TAG, "appointmentEvent is: " + appointmentEvent);
}
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.d(TAG, "Entered: onCreateView");
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule_appointment, container, false);
Log.d(TAG, "container is: " + container);
date = view.findViewById(R.id.appointmentDate);
Log.d(TAG, "date at creation is: " + date);
date.setText("This is a test");
date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Log.d(TAG, "date is initially: " + date.getText());
date.setClickable(true);
date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View view) {
Log.d(TAG, "Date EditText field clicked");
CalendarDialogFragment calendarFragment = new CalendarDialogFragment();
//FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
calendarFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "setFragment");
}
});
.
. (the other EditText entities go here)
.
}

public void saveUserInput(){
Log.d(TAG, "Entered: saveUserInput");
Log.d(TAG, "date is: " + date);
Log.d(TAG, "date now is set to: " + date.getText());
String dateInput = date.getText().toString();
Log.d(TAG, "date at saveUserInput is: " + date);
Log.d(TAG, "dateInput is: " + dateInput);
String timeInput = time.getText().toString();
String notificationInput = notification.getText().toString();
String eventInput = event.getText().toString();
String notesInput = notes.getText().toString();

ContentValues values =  new ContentValues();
values.put(APPOINTMENT_DATE, dateInput);
values.put(APPOINTMENT_TIME, timeInput);
values.put(APPOINTMENT_NOTIFICATION, notificationInput);
values.put(APPOINTMENT_EVENT, eventInput);
values.put(APPOINTMENT_NOTES, notesInput);
Log.d(TAG, "appointment values are: " + values);
}
}
```

The fragment loads in the Activity fine, all TextViews and EditText objects are visible, can be clicked in and text or numbers can be entered.

While the EditText field can be clicked and seems to accept characters, the *onClick* method is never entered.

`date.setText("This is a test");` has no visible effect, the hint text remains onscreen. However,  `date.setText("This is a test");`sets the text for the date variable as LogCat displays: `D/ScheduleAppointmentFragment: date is initially: This is a test` from onCreateView.

The date object is created and is referenced in onCreateView as seen in the LogCat entry *date at creation is: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{6f017c VFED..CL. ......I.0,0-0,0 #7f080036 app:id/appointmentDate}*.

The date object's reference remains the same as seen in the saveUserInput() method's LogCat entry 
*date at saveUserInput is: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{6f017cVFED..CL. ......I.0,0-0,0 #7f080036 app:id/appointmentDate}*.

I enter values in each EditText object that are displayed as entered, yet all variables are loaded via `xxx.getText().toString()` as "" (an empty string) as displayed in LogCat: *appointment values are: appointmentNotification= appointmentEvent=appointmentTime=appointmentDate=This is a test appointmentNotes=* (date was loaded in onCreateView).

I tried the layout as linearlayout and get the same result.

I added date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); as an experiment with no success. It isn't needed nor used in the other Fragments that do accept user input.

I set `android:inputType="text"` for test.

The other Fragments are loaded in the Activity precisely the same and served as the template for this failing Fragment.

This Fragment is created with the empty constructor, the newInstance method is not called.

Any suggestions as to why this Fragment is not displaying the set value and not holding the entered values?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out your `setClickable()` and `setOnClickListener()` to see if it's interfering with your EditText's default functionality?

Comment: I forget if I did, so I just did that and it made no difference, the set text still doesn't show. However, I just noticed an error further down: I/kob: Unsupported field type provided by app=Tap to set or enter dd/mm/yyyy [CONTEXT service_id=177 ]. There are five of these, one for each EditText field, two are app=Notes and app=Enter and three are app=Tap. I bet that those expose the problem. I didn't notice them before as I was looking at my messages and red or blue text. These are black and so I missed them.

Comment: I found that the error text after the "app=" (see comment above) is the text set in the strings.xml resource file. I can't think of a good reason why these strings would be considered "Unsupported field type provided by" as they are just strings displayed by hint and autofillHints. I use them in other layouts. Am looking into this, but with no success at the time of this posting.

Comment: I deleted the hints and autofillHints lines from the strings.xml resource file and I still have the same problem, but those errors don't appear. So, there's still something odd going on with regards to those xml commands that have nothing to do with my initial problem.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, so I rewrote the code from a functional Fragment and it works.